# Do electrons have structure in quantum gravity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gravity

I have read Luboš Motl's blog and he says in QG electrons must be composite and have structure because QG says there can be no point like particles and everything above the Planck size can be resolved but under it can't so electrons bring above the Planck size must be composite? Does all QG theories say electrons must be composite? Are they?

Comment: Can you post the link. I'd be very surprised if Luboš Motl said electrons were composite, though he may well have said they are extended objects (i.e. a string excitation).

Comment: http://motls.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/the-electron-is-spinning-after-all.html?m=1   He says in QG electrons must be composite. And he means all theories of QG not just string theory.

Comment: The comment is "before the plank scale all particles must have internal structure"

Comment: *Internal structure* doesn't mean *composite*. Note that Motl says: "The electron is not composite in the Standard Model and most likely, it will always be elementary in any quantum field theory correctly and usefully approximating the phenomena around us. But at the end, it's also an extended object – a string or whatever quantum gravity tells you". The term *composite* means *made up from two or more elementary components*. A string has internal structure because it's an extended object, however it is elementary not composite.

Comment: He also says anything above the plank scale must have internal structure and refers to it being like a proton. Internal structure means its composite and so are protons

Comment: He says *so it's qualitatively analogous to the proton*. What precisely he means by this you will have to ask him. For the record, no quantum gravity approach I know requires an electron to be a composite particle.

Answer (score 2):

There are [quantum gravity theories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_gravity) abroad, but the theories that can incorporate the [Standard model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of particle physics are only [string theories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory). Incorporating the SM is important if one aims to come up with a TOF ( a theory of everything). The only reason I know of for quantizing gravity is so that all known forces can be unified in one theoretical framework.

This statement by Lubos which you misinterpret, is within a string theory model that will hopefully materialize  in the future at some point, unifying all forces . The reason it has not been found  up to now is that there are very many theoretical possibilities and unless all of them except the true one are excluded one cannot claim discovering a TOF.

> First, it's not true that the electron is strictly point-like. Before the Planck scale, all particles have to have an internal structure because quantum gravity doesn't allow distances shorter than the Planck length to be resolved. The internal architecture of particles therefore can't be "strictly and sharply point-like". In all perturbative string vacua, the electrons are vibrating strings (occupying space comparable to the string length, a few orders of magnitude longer than the Planck length) and indeed, the spin may be understood as coming from some internal degrees of freedom that are localized at an extended object.

Nowhere in the quote   is implied compositeness, the way the proton is composite made out of three quarks. It talks of extended in dimensions objects. A string has one dimension, its length, a membrane two, etc. This does not mean that a compositeness is assumed. It is a mathematical description.

The non string quantum gravity theories have problems incorporating the SM, which describes the elementary particles so I would suppose that they do not rely on hypothesis of what elementary particles are all about.

Comment: That string theory incorporates SM is a bit optimistic.

Comment: @MBN Well, it has the group structures necessary in a natural manner , which is much more than can be said for other quantizing gravitation theories.